# Aligning an icon to the right inside label tag

Tags: html, css

I tried changing the style of the i tag to 'float:right' in order to align the icon to the right, but it didn't work.
The ideal look would be like the image below. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-2">
    <label for="form-realname" class="d-flex align-items-center">TEXT<i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="float:right;"></i></label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-test" name="test" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is this a bootstrap question? then `ms-auto` or `ml-auto` to the icon depending on which evrsion you use.

Comment: I'm currently using version 5, thus ms-auto was the one I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use flex `justify-content` with `space-between`. Also, please do not use float to *align items* in new code, this should be considered legacy.

It looks like you are using Bootstrap so you can simply add the `justify-content-between` class to your label.

More info here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-2">
        <label for="form-test" class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">TEXT
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle d-block" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-test" name="test" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, note that the `for` attribute should point to the `id` of the input it is describing (in this case `form-test`).

Comment: one reason to use float is that you actually want to flaot an element or in email-templates

Comment: There is almost always a better solution nowadays. No?

Comment: What alternative do you know for floating an element ( actually floating not aligning next to each other)  or what alternative do you know that is fully supported by all email clients?

Comment: Hum, e-mail clients are difficult, indeed.

Comment: But you are, right about the float vs aligning, I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: I wasn't aware of 'justify-content-between'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simplified solution for your problem. You can paste it on some js and html playground (codesandbox, jsfiddle, etc.) to understand the idea

You can base on it to do what you need.

```
<body>
  <style>
    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: 200px;
    }
    .input-div {
      width: 200px;
    }
  </style>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-2">
      <div class="flex-container">
        <label>TEXT1</label>
        <label>TEXT2</label> // Your <i> tag goes here
      </div>
      <div>
        <input class="input-div" type="text" class="form-control" id="form-test" name="test" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The idea is:

- You need to set the input width and the container of the label and icon the same. (With bootstrap, you can use class `col` for them)
- The label and icon are not nested as you did, separate it out like I did
- Styling the label and icon container with `flex`, and `justify-content: space-between`